# GCC 4.0, 4.2 and LLVM ABI Compatibility

Tags: xcode, gcc, llvm, binary-compatibility

Are the three main compiler flavors supported by Xcode (gcc 4.0, 4.2, and llvm) binary-compatible with one another? What kind of gotchas and corner cases should I be aware of when bringing a multi-library project up to speed with the most recent Xcode tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang is ABI-compatible with code generated by gcc. Clang also includes experimental support for some newer Objective-C ABIs, but compiling for the newer ABI requires flags, and generated code can be mixed with GCC-generated code anyway.

Comment: Is clang's C++ ABI compatible with g++?

Comment: clang is a c++ compiler :)

Comment: clang++ is a C++ compiler. A more recent answer on the duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682748/is-clang-abi-same-as-g explains that for C++ there does not seem to be a commitment to full ABI compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

A minor gotcha is that if you want to compile PowerPC code that will run on a G3, you must use GCC 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; we won't need to compile PPC unless Apple returns to it, but good to know in general.