# C++ .a: what affects portability across distros?

Tags: linux, binary, portability

I'm building a `.a` from C++ code. It only depends on the standard library (`libc++`/`libstdc++`).  From general reading, it seems that portability of binaries depends on

- compiler version (because it can affect the ABI). For `gcc`, the ABI is linked to the major version number.
- `libc++`/`libstdc++` versions (because they could pass a `vector<T>` into the .a and its representation could change).

I.e. someone using the `.a` needs to use the same (major version of) the compiler + same standard library.

As far as I can see, if compiler and standard library match, a `.a` should work across multiple distros. Is this right? Or is there gubbins relating to system calls, etc., meaning a `.a` for Ubuntu should be built on Ubuntu, `.a` for CentOS should be built on CentOS, and so on?

Edit: see [If clang++ and g++ are ABI incompatible, what is used for shared libraries in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443646/if-clang-and-g-are-abi-incompatible-what-is-used-for-shared-libraries-in-bi) (though it doens't answer this q.)

Edit 2: I am not accessing any OS features explicitly (e.g. via `system` calls). My only interaction with the system is to open files and read from them.

Comment: You would get much more useful answers if you explained in details what kind of library you are coding!

Comment: BTW, why don't you make your code [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)? I am very reluctant on installing proprietary software on my Linux distro. Quite often, it is a reason (by itself) to avoid doing that (and buying some other product).

Comment: I have written free software myself, but this is for work. Anyway, thank you for your really detailed and helpful answer.

Comment: I am writing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) ([GPLv3+](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) licensed) for work. So you can write free software for work. You may need to convince your manager/stackholder/client that it is better for him/his company. BTW, he'll find out that porting that code (to various distributions) is a lot of work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It only depends on the standard library

It could also depend *implicitly* upon other things (think of resources like fonts, configuration files under `/etc/`, header files under `/usr/include/`, availability of `/proc/`, of `/sys/`,  external programs run by [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html), specific file systems or devices, particular `ioctl`-s, available or required plugins, etc...)

These are kind of details which might make the porting difficult. For example look into [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html).

**The evil is in the details.**

<sup>(in other words, without *a lot* more details, your question don't have much sense)</sup>

Linux is perceived as a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) ecosystem. The usual way of porting something is to recompile it on -or at least for- the target Linux distribution. When you do that several times (for *different* and *many* Linux distros), you'll understand what *details* are significant in *your particular software* (and distributions).

Most of the time, recompiling and porting a library on a different distribution is really easy. Sometimes, it might be hard.

For shared libraries, reading [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), [C++ dlopen miniHowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html), [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), your [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification (see [here](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) for some incomplete list), Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) could be useful.

My recommendation is to prepare binary [packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for various common Linux distributions. For example, a [`.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) for Debian & Ubuntu (some *particular* versions of them).

Of course a `.deb` for Debian might not work on Ubuntu (sometimes it does).

Look also into things like [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) (or [cmake](https://cmake.org/)). You may want at least to have some externally provided `#define`-d preprocessor strings (often passed by `-D` to `gcc` or `g++`) which would vary from one distribution to the next (e.g. on some distributions, you print by `popen`-ing `lp`, on others, by `popen`-ing `lpr`, on others by interacting with some CUPS server etc...). Details matter.

> My only interaction with the system is to open files

But even these vary a lot from one distribution to another one.

It is probable that you won't be able to provide a *single* -and the same one- `lib*.a` for several distributions.

<sup>NB: you probably need to budget more work than what you believe.</sup>