# Is there a way to call method pointer from any class

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way to call any method from any class using pointer?

Something like that:

```
#include <vector>

class AnyClass {
public:
    virtual void call(void* instance, void (*callback)(float value), float value) = 0;
};

class MyClass1 : public AnyClass {
public:
    // void call(void* instance, void ((void *)::*callback)(float value), float value)
    void call(void* instance, void (*callback)(float value), float value)
    {
        MyClass1* obj = (MyClass1*)instance;
        (obj->*(callback))(value);
    }

    void hello(float value)
    {
        printf("hello %f\n", value);
    }
};

class MyClass2 : public AnyClass {
public:
    void call(void* instance, void (*callback)(float value), float value)
    {
        MyClass2* obj = (MyClass2*)instance;
        (obj->*(callback))(value);
    }

    void world(float value)
    {
        printf("world %f\n", value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    struct Caller {
        AnyClass* instance;
        void (*callback)(float value);
        float value;
    };
    Vetcor<Caller> vetcor = { { new MyClass1, &MyClass1::hello, 0.123 }, { new MyClass2, &MyClass2::world, 0.456 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < vetcor.size(); i++) {
        vetcor[i].call(vetcor[i].instance, vetcor[i].callback, vetcor[i].value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the moment I am using template, but it's super annoying cause I am restricted to one class, so I have to create a vector per class. I would love to be able to have a single vector where I can push any method of any class...

Edit:
I wanted to avoid to much code, but to give the context, this is how I solve my problem right now:

```
class Plugin {
public:
    virtual float getValue(int valueIndex) = 0;
    virtual void setValue(int valueIndex, float value) = 0;
    virtual int getValueCount() = 0;
    virtual const char* getValueKey(int valueIndex) = 0;
    virtual int getValueIndex(const char* key) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Val {
protected:
    T* instance;
    float value_f;

public:
    const char* key;
    T& (T::*callback)(float value);

    Val(T* instance, float initValue, const char* _key, T& (T::*_callback)(float value))
        : instance(instance)
        , value_f(initValue)
        , key(_key)
        , callback(_callback)
    {
    }

    inline float get()
    {
        return value_f;
    }

    void set(float value)
    {
        value_f = range(value, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    void call(float value)
    {
        (instance->*(callback))(value);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Mapping : public Plugin {
public:
    std::vector<Val<T>*> mapping;

    Mapping(std::vector<Val<T>*> mapping)
        : mapping(mapping)
    {
    }

    int getValueIndex(const char* key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mapping.size(); i++) {
            if (strcmp(mapping[i]->key, key) == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int getValueCount()
    {
        return mapping.size();
    }
    float getValue(int valueIndex)
    {
        return mapping[valueIndex]->get();
    }
    void setValue(int valueIndex, float value)
    {
        mapping[valueIndex]->call(value);
    }

    const char* getValueKey(int valueIndex)
    {
        return mapping[valueIndex]->key;
    }
};

class DemoClass : public Mapping<DemoClass> {
public:
    Val<DemoClass> val1 = { this, 0.5, "VAL1", &DemoClass::setVal1 };
    Val<DemoClass> val2 = { this, 0.0, "VAL2", &DemoClass::setVal2 };

    DemoClass()
        : Mapping({ &val1, &val2 })
    {
    }

    // Do some stuff

    DemoClass& setVal1(float value)
    {
        val1.set(value);
        // Do some stuff
        return *this;
    }

    DemoClass& setVal2(float value)
    {
        val2.set(value);
        // do some stuff
        return *this;
    };
};

class AnotherClass : public Mapping<AnotherClass> {
public:
    Val<AnotherClass> myVal = { this, 0.5, "MYVAL", &AnotherClass::setMyVal };

    AnotherClass()
        : Mapping({ &myVal })
    {
    }

    AnotherClass& setMyVal(float value)
    {
        myVal.set(value);
        // Do some stuff
        return *this;
    }
};
```

`DemoClass` and `AnotherClass` are some shared library and I load them using `dlopen`. Then again using some config file, I can set value by doing something like: `obj.setValue(obj.getValueIndex("MYVAL"), 0.123)`. It work perfectly, but in some case I feel like some limitation (or most likly lacking some C++ knowledge), but for example if I do some inheritance on `AnotherClass` to define some extra function, then it's start to get complicated. So somehow, if I could have a pointer on an object and then a pointer to a method, it could simplify a lot my code. But I might beleive that it not possible...

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which can hold multiple types.

Comment: `vetcor[i].call(...)` I'm not sure I understand. `struct Caller` doesn't have a member named `call`. That said, my guess is you are looking for `std::function`. The search term for future research is "type erasure".

Comment: `std::variant` is very interresting, the problem seem that I still need to assign the type of the different variant upfront... But how can I do if I don't know them. I am loading my object using `dlopen`, the only thing I know is the virtual class they are inheriting from.

Comment: Why does it have to be without using templates?

Comment: Because right now I am using template and I am limited to the type I defined in the template. However, if there is way to pass to the template a generic type, I am also fine with it ;-)

Comment: _"it's super annoying cause I am restricted to one class, so I have to create a vector per class"_  - You could create a base class that you inherit from. See `dynlib.hpp`/`dynlib.cpp` and the derived class in `foobarloader.hpp`/`foobarloader.cpp` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56971263/7582247)

Comment: I edited my post by adding my current solution to solve my problem. Hoping that it can give a better idea of my struggles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps this would point in a useful direction.

```
using Callback_t = std::function<void()>;

template <typename T>
Callback_t MakeCallback(void (T::*f)(float), float val) {
  T* p = new T;
  return [=]() { (p->*f)(val); }
}

std::vector<Callback_t> vetcor = {
  MakeCallback(&MyClass1::hello, 0.123),
  MakeCallback(&MyClass2::world, 0.456)};

for (int i = 0; i < vetcor.size(); i++) {
    vetcor[i]();
}
```

This leaks instances of `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`, but so does your example. Lifetime management is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Woooow, amazing!! I think this can help me a lot ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't this call `delete` or something? I see `new` and no `delete`.

Comment: If we call `delete` the the annoymous function will not be able to call anymore the method. We should only delete the object once we don't need it anymore. We could eventually call delete in the annoymous function, but all depends what you want to achieve...

Comment: @JanSchultke Well, something somewhere should call `delete`. I didn't understand the OP's design well enough to decide what and where. I replicated the original example, leaks and all. I made a note of this below my code; I suppose you haven't looked that far down.

Comment: `return [val]() { /*static*/T t; (t.*f)(val); }` would avoid memleak.