# Undefined reference when compiling with gcc and using clang compiled code

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

I have two projects

1. the first project is compiled with clang
2. the second project is compiled with gcc and uses code from the first project

The second project fails with an undefined reference error to a function with type traits:

```
CMakeFiles/RobotAPICore.dir/remoterobot/RobotStateObserver.cpp.o: In function      
`RobotStateObserver::udpatePoseDatafields(std::map<std::string, IceInternal::Handle<FramedPoseBase>, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, 
IceInternal::Handle<FramedPoseBase> > > > const&)':
/home/user/RobotAPI/source/RobotAPI/libraries/core/remoterobot/RobotStateObserver.cpp:149: 
undefined reference to `Variant::Variant<float>(float const&, boost::disable_if_c<boost::is_base_of<VariantDataClass, float>::value||boost::is_pointer<float>::value, void>::type*)'
```

If I compile both projects with the same compiler, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: When compiling with clang++, do you use -stdlib=libstdc++ (should be compatible with g++) or -stdlib=libc++ (not compatible)? Which versions of clang/gcc?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't do that.

Don't mix toolchains.

Comment: So, if I want to ship my code compiled with clang, nobody can use it with gcc? And the other way around it just works by chance? How do you know with which toolchain a installed library was compiled with?

Comment: IMO this depends on the type of data your project exposes. C has a standardised binary interface (ABI), whereas c++ does not (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492180/c-abi-issues-list). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682748/is-clang-abi-same-as-g

Comment: @SerJothanChanes: Yeah, that's right. FYI the question is tagged C++, so..